# What is the point of TURNS in WebRTC

Tags: tls, webrtc

WebRTC makes use of `TURN-Servers` if the direct peer to peer connection fails. There are two protocols available: `TURN` and `TURNS` (TURN over TLS).

According to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Using_data_channels#Security):

> All data transferred using WebRTC is encrypted.

If all data sent via a data channel is end to end encrypted with `DTLS` by default, why does `TURNS` even exists?

Isn't `TURNS` only encrypting the connection between the server and the client?

Wouldn't that be unnecessary overhead?

**EDIT** - Why not simply use plain `TURN`without any server/client encryption? I know what `TURN-servers` are used for, but I do not get why we would want to encrypt the connection to the `TURN-server.` Because of the `DTLS` encryption between the peers, the `TURN-server` cannot read any of the transferred data. Hence nobody else can, so why even bother adding another layer of encryption?

Comment: Similar question for STUN: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/139707/what-information-can-be-leaked-via-unencrypted-stun-transmission

Answer (score 7):

One reason is for better firewall traversal. You can get past some stricter firewalls with TURN/TLS over port 443 to disguise WebRTC traffic as HTTPS traffic.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to better firewall traversal. Without wrapping the TURN payload in TLS, An eavesdropper would be able to see the IP address of the peer (the destination of the relayed traffic). Depending on your threat model this may or may not be important.

Excerpt from the RFC

> The primary protocol content of the messages is the ***IP address of the
> peer***.  If it is important to prevent an eavesdropper on a TURN
> connection from learning this, TURN can be run over TLS.

[rfc5766#section-17.1.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5766#section-17.1.6)

Comment: Isn't the TURN server receiving/sending packets from/to the each peer? The IPv4/6 source/destination addresses and ports can't be protected with TLS, else the packet couldn't be routed to its destination.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding Traversal Using Relays around NAT (TURN) seems more aimed towards better traversal of firewalls behind NAT, [RFC5766](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5766). So, although the TURN server handles encryption (like a web server handles HTTPS), it's not the primary use of TURN servers.

> [image: TURN Server]

If direct communication is allowed, but the firewall blocked signalling, no initiation would take place: no P2P communication would be established.

> [image: WebRTC]

[Image source, and further explanation](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/)

TURN's purpose of firewall traversal could equally be achieved by using an SSL VPN or OpenVPN to circumvent restrict firewall(s).

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to include anything about the difference between TURN and TURNS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! :) But my question aims at why we need to encrypt the TURN connection with TLS. As far as I understand TLS is obsolete in this case.

Answer (score 0):

There are three transport modes - TURN/UDP, TURN/TCP & TURN/TLS. Depending on LAN FW policy, browser will select the least restrictive transport mode.